# iOS: dyld: Library not loaded with SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, frameworks, sqlite.swift

I'm using SQLite for the extension in an app.
 Everything work fine in Simulator, but error has occurred when i run the app in my device.

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SQLite.framework/SQLite Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/898AED60-6F5F-482C-83FC-A55655599429/*.app/PlugIns/*.appex/* Reason: image not found
```

I have to add framework to "Copy files" section in the extension.
Trouble solved.

But when i run the app on my device, i have to uncheck on option "Copy only when installing"
and when i run my app on simulator, i have to check on it. If i didn't new error will show:

```
error: make directory /Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*-dlklrcpbpykobgbkaophrsrhssxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/*.appex/Frameworks/SQLite.framework: File exists
```

How to solve it. And if i archive and upload app to appstore, whats about this option, how to get it run with simulator and device also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten rid of this error by adding framework to the `Copy files` section in extension, but also remove the framework in `Linked framework and Libraries` to avoid this error.

Answer (score 5):

In your target, select *General* tab. In *Embedded Binaries* section add your SQL.framework. This is for dynamic libs. *Clean* an *run* on simulator and device.

If does not works, back to target, *Build Setting* tab. In your *copy files* phase, uncheck *Copy only when installing*, check *Code Sign On Copy*, and select *Destination* like *Frameworks*

This allow archive ipa with no problems.

Comment: Which target? extension of the app? i want to use SQLite in my app's extension. And in the `Build Setting` tab, there is nothing called `Copy files` It only available in `Build Phrases` tab. The trouble is i've done it in my extension, but it required me to check on "Copy only when installing" if i test the app in simulator, and i have to uncheck it if i test the app in device!